# Compilation error in Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: sql, function, oracle11g

I have been staring at this hours trying to figure out why it won't run, and cannot see any syntax error which should stop this from compiling, but I am nonetheless getting the following errors:

```
Error(6,1): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(22,7): PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

The function I am trying to create is as follows:

```
create or replace function caps_get_Uoffer_count_BD(ayrc in varchar2
,mcrc in varchar2)
return number
is
app_count number;
begin
select count(*)
from
(select distinct cap.cap_stuc,cap.cap_apfs , cap.cap_seqn from 
intuit.srs_cap cap 
,intuit.srs_apf apf 
,intuit.srs_ioi ioi 
where cap.cap_ayrc = ayrc
and cap.cap_mcrc = mcrc
and apf.apf_stuc = cap.cap_stuc 
and apf.apf_seqn = cap.cap_apfs 
and apf.apf_recd <= to_date('1501'||substr(ayrc,1,4),'DDMMYYYY')
and cap.cap_stuc = ioi.ioi_stuc
and cap.cap_mcrc = ioi.ioi_mcrc
and ioi.ioi_iodc ='PAPERLESS'
and cap.cap_stac like 'A%'
and cap.cap_idrc in ('U','UF','UI','UD','CFU','CFUF','CIUI','CIUF','CIUD','CIU','CFUI','CFUD'))
return(app_count);
end;
```

Database is Oracle 11g. Can anyone help?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: missing a semicolon at the end of the query ));

Comment: you are also missing the `into app_count` part.

Comment: Where should that go exactly @a_horse_with_no_name?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/selectinto_statement.htm#i36066